# JPA : weird Cascade delete behaviour, OneToMany. FK Violation when using two seperate DAO

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, cascade

Parent : StaffGroup

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "STAFF_GROUP")
public class StaffGroup implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="staffGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child: Staff

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "STAFF")
public class Staff implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // Relationships
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STAFF_GROUP_ID")
    private StaffGroup staffGroup;
```

This is a JavaFX application that uses JPA and MySQL as a database.

I have a DAO for each entity (staff and staffGroup). And A Logic Class Called StaffGate like this:

```
public class StaffGate {
    // GRP
    private List<StaffGroup> staffGrps = new ArrayList<>();
    private StaffGroupDAO groupDAO = new StaffGroupDAO();

    // Staff
    private static List<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList<>();
    private StaffDAO staffDao = new StaffDAO();

    public void removeFromDBAndMemory(StaffGroup element) {
        groupDAO.remove(element);
        staffGrps.remove(element);
    }
    //...
```

Now for The View I have One Class called StaffView, this class is where the View is created, and it has TWO StaffGate instances, one for GroupStaff operations and another for Staff.

```
public class StaffView {
    private StaffGate staffGate = new StaffGate();// Grp operations
    private StaffGate staffGatestf = new StaffGate();// Staff operations
```

Now, I can create a group, and staff, and they get persisted, I can delete a Staff entity too. The Problem is When I want to delete A StaffGroup entity, it throws an FK Violation Exception

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-06-25 10:35:20.567--UnitOfWork(1053875258)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`school-finma`.`staff`, CONSTRAINT `FK_STAFF_STAFF_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STAFF_GROUP_ID`) REFERENCES `staff_group` (`ID`))
Error Code: 1451
Call: DELETE FROM STAFF_GROUP WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(StaffGroup [id=4, name=Drivers, imageByteInfoEntity=null, staffs={[]}, school=School [id=1, name=Banafsaj, schoolType=USA, address=null, creationDate=2016-06-13, image=ImageByteInfoEntity [id=1, byteImage.length=2793472, width=1024, height=682], active=true], active=true])
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`school-finma`.`staff`, CONSTRAINT `FK_STAFF_STAFF_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STAFF_GROUP_ID`) REFERENCES `staff_group` (`ID`))
Error Code: 1451
Call: DELETE FROM STAFF_GROUP WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(StaffGroup [id=4, name=Drivers, imageByteInfoEntity=null, staffs={[]}, school=School [id=1, name=Banafsaj, schoolType=USA, address=null, creationDate=2016-06-13, image=ImageByteInfoEntity [id=1, byteImage.length=2793472, width=1024, height=682], active=true], active=true])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at derbyware.school.dao.AbstractFacade.remove(AbstractFacade.java:49)
    at derbyware.school.logic.StaffGate.removeFromDBAndMemory(StaffGate.java:49)
```

I do have cascade.all in place.

And The problem does **NOT** occure when I use **ONLY ONE StaffGate** instance.

Why does this happens?? and how can I fix it??

I added this line before the call to the deletion method in StaffGate, and it still the same problem: `staffGatestf = new StaffGate();`

**Update**

What I mean by

> And The problem does NOT occure when I use ONLY ONE StaffGate instance

is that in the Class: StaffView I remove: staffGatestf instance, and work only with staffGate. In this case no exception occures.

Comment: Have you tried staffGrps.clear(); before deleting group itself, or i'd bet it would work with orphanRemoval=true at @OneToMany also, altought it looks redundant

Comment: Tried what you have said and still the same exception, staffGatestf.getAllGrps().clear();
staffGatestf.getAllStaffs().clear(); + remove from memory before DB + orphanRemoval=true

Comment: Try without clearing, just the annotation parameter

Comment: just did, nope still not working

Comment: I didn't get it, what did you mean about just one staffgroup  instance not throwing exception? You tried only one staffGate at view? Would you paste more of your tiers? Dao, This view, fully, and where you call it

Comment: It is not clear why you need two `StaffGate` instances and how you are using them.

Comment: Is your collection populated when you call remove on the StaffGroup?  A common problem with bidirectional relationships is many people do not maintain both sides, leaving one side to become inconsistent with what is in the database.  JPA can only delete Staff members that are in the StaffGroup's staffs list, so if it is empty when you call remove, it will not cascade the remove to the Staff instances resulting in a constraint violation if some exist in the database.  Make sure you are setting both sides of your relationships, and try calling em.refresh() before the delete.

Comment: You're Right. StaffGroup.List of Staff is empty when I call remove on it, Thanks now I know why. Can you re-enter your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by removing only one instance of StaffGate. But if any one know how to fix I would appreciate it